# why this error occurs ? Error: Cannot find module 'arg' while running ts-node filename.ts

Tags: typescript, ts-node

```
$ ts-node basic.ts
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtSnZ.png)

I tried npm i -g arg but still error occurs

I tried to run a typescript file using ts-node in ubuntu 22.04 and expecting the output of typescript file

Answer (score -1):

Can you try "sudo npm i arg" inside your project directory?